# QML gridview how to use different cell widths

Tags: gridview, qml

I would like to implement a simple keyboard.

All keys have the same width except for shift, space and delete.

I use a ListModel based on QAbstractListModel and a qml file as delegate.
Based on the cell content I dynamically calculate the width of the key (not yet pretty but serves the purpose).

It works for only shift key
[image]

Desired arrangement (yellow = space key, green = delete key)
[image]

Current result
[image]
But how can I now define in the last line that the space key does not start in column 2 but in column 3 and the delete key does not start in column 3 but in column 9?

KeyboardDelegate qml

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts  

Item { id: item 
    property real p_height
    property real p_width
    property string p_selectedButton
    property string p_selectedBorder
    property string p_releasedButton
    property string p_releasedBorder
    property bool v_selected: grid.currentIndex == index
    property real v_cellwidth: r_text == "#space" ? p_width * 6 : r_text == "#shift" || r_text == "#delete" ? p_width * 2 : p_width 

    Rectangle { height: p_height - 2; width: v_cellwidth - 2; radius: 4
        color: v_selected ? p_selectedButton : p_releasedButton
        border.color: v_selected ? p_selectedBorder : p_releasedBorder
        
        Label { anchors.centerIn: parent; text: r_text }

        MouseArea { anchors.fill: parent; onClicked: function(mouse) { grid.currentIndex = index }}
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log("Keyboarddelegate " + r_text + " x " + v_dnywidth)

    }

}
```

Keyboard qml

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
import System.ColorsEnum 1.0
import System.SizesEnum 1.0

Rectangle { id: keyboard; 
    property string v_selectedButton: cp_display.getColor(Colors.ButtonSelected)
    property string v_selectedBorder: cp_display.getColor(Colors.ButtonSelectedBorder)
    property string v_releasedButton: cp_display.getColor(Colors.ButtonReleased)
    property string v_releasedBorder: cp_display.getColor(Colors.ButtonReleasedBorder)

    GridView { id: grid; width: parent.width; height: parent.height; flow: GridView.FlowLeftToRight
        model: cp_screen.keyboardListModel
        cellWidth: parent.width / 10
        cellHeight: (parent.height / 5) - 5
        delegate: KeyboardDelegate { p_height: grid.cellHeight; p_width: grid.cellWidth; p_selectedButton: v_selectedButton; p_selectedBorder: v_selectedBorder; p_releasedButton: v_releasedButton; p_releasedBorder: v_releasedBorder }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are better off using a GridLayout with a Repeater

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, `Flow` could be used to solve the problem. To have it work, you have to set `width` of your `Flow` and size your child delegates accurately so that they wrap precisely when you need them. Here, I set each delegate to 55px width + 5px margin = 60px width. Using the first row as a guide, we want to fit 10 buttons per row, so, the `Flow` needs to be 600px width. When I come across the last 3 buttons, I give them a bigger width, so, in total, with the 5px spacing, it will occupy the 600px width.

Another improvement is you can replace your `Item` + `Rectangle` + `MouseArea` component with a `Button` component with a custom `background` property.

```
    Flow {
        width: 60 * 10
        spacing: 5
        Repeater {
            model: `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
q w e r t z y u i o
a s d f g h j k l -
\\ y x c v b n m . /
#shift #space #delete`.split(/\s/)
            Button {
                id: btn
                property int span:
                     modelData === '#shift' && 2
                  || modelData === '#space' && 6
                  || modelData === '#delete' && 2
                  || 1
                width: span * 60 - 5
                height: 35
                text: modelData
                focus: index === 0
                background: Rectangle {
                    border.color: btn.focus ? "cyan" : "#888"
                    color: btn.pressed ? "#888" : "#ccc"
                    radius: 5
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: Thanks very much, interesting approach. Are there advantages or disadvantages in using flow compared to grid layout? And is it possible to change the index / the marked button from qt / c++?

Comment: For the Flow solution you are in charge of doing the size calculations yourself. GridLayout is doing that for you.  So the first question you have to ask yourself is if you want to have the full control over sizing issues  (leading to more code) or if you go the common way and letting the Layout doing the work. Both ways are just fine...it depends on your needs.

Comment: @JürgenLutz in hindsight, after posting that answer, I was actually one step short of absolute positioning. From the standpoint of it being a GridLayout question, this type of answer is actually the furthest from.

Answer (score 2):

Use a GridLayout and a Repeater:

```
GridLayout {
    id: keyboard
    columns: 10
    anchors.fill: parent

    Repeater {
        model: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0",
            "q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "z", "u", "i", "o", "p",
            "a", "s", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "-",
            "\\", "y", "x", "c", "v", "b", "n", "m", ".", "/",
            "shift", "space", "delete"]

        Rectangle {
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.columnSpan: {
                if (modelData === "shift") {
                    return 2;
                } else if (modelData === "space") {
                    return 5;
                } else if (modelData === "delete") {
                    return 3;
                }

                return 1;
            }

            Button {
                anchors.fill: parent
                text: modelData
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ends up like this:

[image: Keyboard Example]

Comment: We can rewrite `Layout.columnSpan` as a 1-liner: `Layout.columnSpan: ({"shift":2,"space":5,"delete":3})[modelData] || 1`

Comment: We could do that...to create unmaintainable code ;)